# Python Tkinter Entry Box For Loop Creation

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to make a loop that creates a tkinter label each iteration (works fine) then creates 5 entry boxes next to each other (using a for loop and a function).

Initially, it stopped because the variables weren't defined (I fixed this by defining them twice (once in the loop and once before defining the function)) which is not ideal but fixes that problem.

Now I suspect the function can't see the update in colnum because it is only creating one entry box per name instead of 5.

```
    def create_entry(win):
        inputarray.append(Entry(win, width=2, font=font2))
        inputarray[a].grid(row=rownum, column=colnum)

    for i in range(0, x):
        label1 = Label(Solo, text=StudentsArray1[a][0]+" "+StudentsArray1[a][1], font=font4, bg="white")
        label1.grid(row=rownum, column=1)
        colnum=2
        for y in range (0,5):
            create_entry(Solo)
            colnum = colnum + 1
        rownum = rownum + 1
        a = a + 1
```

[image: This is what my window looks like]

Comment: *"it is only creating one entry box per name instead of 5."* `range(0, 4)` results in `4` but you get 4 `Entry` to see it resize the window.

Comment: The window has no set geometry, it will be big enough to fit all content on it (when you enlarge it there are no more widgets).

Comment: *"Look at the updated image"*: I have tried your code and it works for me. Insert `print(colnum)` into `def create_entry(...` to see it the value changes.

Comment: `create_entry()` isn't necessarily calling `.grid()` on the Entry it just created, instead it's always calling `.grid()` on the Entry at index `a`.  So you're actually creating five Entries per person, but only one of them is being made visible (five times).  To refer to the Entry you just appended to the list, use `inputarray[-1]`.